# Авторизация через Cookies в ASP .NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Авторизация работает только по протоколу HTTPS.

В конфигурации сервисов

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options => //CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    });
```

В конвейере

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Метод, через который проходит авторизация после проверки пользователя

```
    private async Task Authenticate(string userName)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, userName)
        };
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    }
```

Если в свойствах отладки включаю SSL, то авторизация работает, иначе после `SignInAsync` я попадаю снова на страницу логина (в этот момент `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false`)

при публикации на локальном IIS то же самое. Работает только через HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не могли бы показать детально содержимое вашего `Startup.cs`, а также метода контроллера, из которого вызывается метод `Authenticate()`? По предоставленной вами информации создал пустой проект .net core 2.0, добавил только ваш конфиг и метод, воспроизвести не удалось. Свойство `IsAuthenticated` устанавливается в `true`. Посмотрите пожалуйста,ссылка на тестовый проект https://github.com/AntonAlekseevAA/CookieAuthExample/tree/master/CookieHttpSchema
Если проблем не возникнет, сравните с вашим кодом.